# How to keep optimization search within bounds in Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm solving a (constrained) nonlinear minimization problem with three variables (w,V,m). Given w the minimization problem is (constrained) linear for (V,m). The linear minimization problem is defined for w in [w_0, w_1].

The way I've set up the problem is that given w, I'm solving a constrained linear program and then I'm minimizing it over w with `bounds = ((w_0, w_1),)` the range of w as bounds. I'm running into problems when the minimization over w searches outside it's bounds i.e. to a region where the linear program is not defined.

Is there a way to restrict the search to not go outside the provided bounds?
If not are there alternatives? Pass tighter bounds? Make the objective function return a large value if it is passed a value outside the bounds?

I'm sorry for not being able to provide a minimal working example.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog,minimize

def objective(w):
A_ub,b_ub = constraints(w)
results = linprog(c,A_ub = A_ub,b_ub=b_ub)
return results.fun

bounds = ((w_0,w_1),)
x0 = (w_0+w_1)/2
minimize(objective,x0,bounds)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something that might work is reparametrizing/redifining the variable `w`, so that it never leaves the bounds. If `x` goes between -infinity and infinity, then

w = a + (b-a)/(1 + exp(-x))

will be in the (a, b) interval.

Just to be clear, you should set `x` as the argument to optimize in the `minimize` function, and include `w` with this formula. Whatever `x` you get, you're guaranteed that the `w` will be within bounds.

When is this a bad idea? Definitely if you think you might have a corner solution at either a or b. Other than that, I think it usually works, but please report back to see if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

One can classify the approaches to solve constrained optimization problems into two classes:

- (1) **Feasible methods**: every iterate will satisfy the constraints
- (2) **Infeasible methods**: iterates do not need to satisfy the constraints until convergence

So using a feasible method is natural for your case. Sadly scipy's docs are a bit unclear about this characteristic in regards to the available algorithms.

I'm pretty sure, that [L-BFGS-B](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html#optimize-minimize-lbfgsb) is the way to go here (as you only need bound-constraints!)

Comment: Even more sophisticated infeasible path solvers (eg MINOS) will not evaluate functions and gradients for x outside their bounds. Infeasible is not identical to bound violations. For real world problems it is important for a solver to ensure we do evaluations only for  `lb<=x<=ub`. We use that to protect against domain errors (e.g. log(x) for negative x).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for your comment. I never used MINOS and can't remember any internals that i might have read in the past about that solver but i always had the feeling, that some/most of the general-purpose NLP solvers will evaluate infeasible points during optimization (COBYLA would be some [example](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2007-July/012955.html)). I can even imagine advantages regarding convergence-proofs. The question is now: Am i wrong or are your impressions bounded to commercial solvers.

Comment: Yes points may be infeasible, but the bounds on the structural variables are obeyed when evaluating functions (for good solvers). Ie. x is between the bounds but the equations may still be infeasible. Note that feasible path methods may actually be infeasible; in my terminology feasible path means once you are feasible you stay feasible (basically a strict phase I/phase II approach). E.g. CONOPT is a feasible path algorithm but will accept an initial point that is infeasible.